# How to move the snake with finger touch input without using keyboard inputs in turtle python?

Tags: python, pygame, python-turtle

I am trying to use Pygame. fingerdown,ondrag  and onclickscreen methode but all does not work correctly,I need to move the snake normally using finger touch because I don't currently have a keyboard
any help please? I need to move it using turtle-only

```
def on_screen_click(x, y):
   screen_width = (window.window_width() )// 2
   screen_height =(window.window_height()) // 2
   if x > screen_width:
     if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"
  elif x < (-screen_width):
     if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"
  elif y >screen_height :
    if head.direction != "down":
         head.direction = "up"
 elif y< (-screen_height):
    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"
```

`window.listen() window.onscreenclick(on_screen_click)`